# Intersection Observer isn't working elements having less than 50% visibility on viewport

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I Have added an Intersection Observer for image lazy loading. But for some reason, if a `div` element is present on the viewport lesser than 50% visibility the Intersection Observer isn't loading the image.

I want to load the image even when it's present 0% to 100% on the viewport. Here is my IntersectionObserver instance:

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
let listenerCallbacks = new WeakMap();
let observer;

function handleIntersections(entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (listenerCallbacks.has(entry.target)) {
            let cb = listenerCallbacks.get(entry.target);

            if (entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                listenerCallbacks.delete(entry.target);
                cb();
            }
        }
    });
}

function getIntersectionObserver() {
    if (observer === undefined) {
        observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersections, {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
        });
    }
    return observer;
}

export function useIntersection(elem, callback) {
    useEffect(() => {
        let target = elem.current;
        let observer = getIntersectionObserver();
        listenerCallbacks.set(target, callback);
        observer.observe(target);

        return () => {
            listenerCallbacks.delete(target);
            observer.unobserve(target);
        };
    }, []);
}
```

Current result:

[image: Result snippet ---]

What I want:

[image: What i'm wanting ---]

Answer (score 1):

Having `threshold: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]` would  run the callback every time visibility passes another 10%, so you would be over-fetching.

Since you want to fetch as soon as a tiny bit of the `div` is visible, set the `threshold` to 0, like `threshold:0`, and change your `if` statement inside `handleIntersections` to:

```
if (entry.isIntersecting)
```

Lastly  it's also related to how fast you are scrolling and how fast your back end is responding, and on how big the image is.

Reference on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: Not solving the issue

Comment: Are you sure it ins't related to how fast you are scrolling and how fast your back end is responding? This also depends on how big the image is.